# python stop a worker's function via threadpool

Tags: python, pyqt5, threadpool, worker

I am building a GUI that it's purpose is to run few tests on a controller.
my original project (which will not brought here because it is very long, instead I wrote another code that I think demonstrating what I want to achieve) is separated to four parts:

1. The ui file, created via the designer - `"file A"`
2. A file containing a class. It's only purpose is to send and receive messages to the controller -  `"File B"`
3. A file containing a class. It's only purpose is to receive information from the worker, process it and send back calculations back to the worker - `"File C"`
4. A file that is the operative file. This file contains the functions of the GUI and the Worker class. -`"File D"` Through this file I basically pass the worker the info, the worker then send this info to File C, gets it back, and push it back to the GUI. As mentions, all communication to the controller is being made via the worker, using functions written down in `"File C"`

Right now I am struggling with this: Let's say I am starting to run a test, but I want to stop in the middle. I can't figure out how to do this.

Below is a short code, with similar idea to what I described above:

`runstop.py`  is like `"File A"`, containing the designer output:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(311, 123)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 50, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 50, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 80, 75, 23))
        self.lbl.setObjectName("lbl")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start Timer"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stop Timer"))
```

`EX.py` is like `"File C"` - basically send back some info to the worker:

```
from datetime import datetime
from PyQt5 import QtTest
class EX():
    def __init__(self,lbl): 
        self.lbl=lbl
    def time(self):
        QtTest.QTest.qWait(1000)
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        self.lbl.setText(current_time)
```

`runstopoper.py` is like `"File D"` - the operative part of the project, containing also the worker:

```
from runstop import Ui_MainWindow
from EX import EX
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys
try:
    import queue
except ImportError:
    import Queue as queue

class Worker(QtCore.QRunnable):
    def __init__(self,q,lbl):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.Q=q
        print("worker up")
        self.ex=EX(lbl)
    def gettime(self):
        self.ex.time()

class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ApplicationWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.threadpool=QtCore.QThreadPool()        
        self.Q=queue.Queue()
        self.ui.pushButton_2.setEnabled(False)
        self.worker=Worker(self.Q,self.ui.lbl)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.startTime)

    def startTime(self):
        print("Started!")
        self.ui.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.setEnabled(True)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateTime)
        self.timer.start()

    def updateTime(self):
        self.worker.gettime()
    def stopTime(self):
        print("stop?")
        ###how do I stop without stopping timer?###
    def closeEvent(self,event):
            sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = ApplicationWindow()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So, my question is how can I stop the worker when I click stop **WITHOUT** having to stop the `QTimer`?
I thought maybe I could use the `QThreadPool` to stop it, but couldn't figure out a way how.
Also, I do not want to "kill" the whole worker, as I want to have the option to start the timer again (and it isn't possible without creating a new worker, but a worker is created within the init, and not when clicking "start")

I Hope everything is understandable - if it's not, please let me know so I can provide more information.
Any suggestion or idea would be very much appreciated!

EDIT:
I changed to code a little bit to make it a little more similar to my original code.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by "kill the worker"? Besides the QTimer, I don't see anything being started in your code.

Comment: The worker is receiving info non-stop from it's self.ex, and I want it to stop receiving info, without stopping the clock

Comment: Maybe I'm not reading it correctly, but it doesnt' seem so. QRunnable requires you to implement [`run()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrunnable.html#run).  In your code you're just calling `gettime()` each time QTimer timeouts, then it calls `time()` which in turn just waits a second and changes the label. I don't see any "non-stop" process in the EX class, right now it's just like setting a new text to the label each cycle of QTimer.

Comment: my question is basically how can I stop this run, without stopping the timer.. If you look at the updated code, i can just call the gettime function without the timer intervals... in that case, how would you stop the worker from getting info in this case?

Comment: You don't understand. With your code, the worker is not running. It's just an instance of Worker class, but except for calling self.ex.time() (which returns immediately) whenever QTimer timeouts, it does absolutely nothing else in the meantime. If you want to stop the calls on `worker.gettime()`, then disconnect the timeout signal from `updateTime`; if you want to stop calls on `ex.time()` use an internal variable that calls `time()` only if that variable is True, and set that variable when you want this to happen.